# Update a column within a table for a record only if that same record has additional events in a separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to update a column within a table for a record only if that same record has additional events in a separate table. Here is what I have so far:

> t1 - Table 1  t2 - table 2 c* - generic column

```
Update t1 
Set c ='6'
From t1
Inner Join t2 on t1.c = t2.c 
Where t2.c1 = '339' and t2.c2 ='0'
```

Basically, I would like to know if the specifics in the where clause are enough to check for events in t2 that correspond with a record that is within t1. Hopefully this makes sense. Feel free to let me know if I have explained this poorly, I tend to think everyone is in my head and knows my thoughts so i may be missing some important details.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: *I would like to know if the specifics in the where clause are enough to check for events in t2 that correspond with a record that is within t1.* -- since you are using `INNER JOIN`, you're query is already correct and enough.

Comment: It is SQL 2012 Standard.

Comment: Thank you! I just wanted to make sure it was accurate. I have had some trouble with UPDATE statements in the past.

Comment: Please note that `t2.c = '339' and t2.c ='0'` will never be true

Comment: @Kaf oh i missed that, you are correct.

Comment: I'm confused. You have  `Where t2.c = '339' and t2.c ='0'` How that could ever be True?

Comment: @PM77-1 there is only one value of the column for every row. `:D` Remember that the condition is checking for every row.

Comment: Right! Sorry! That should read t2.c1 = '339' and t2.c2 ='0'

Comment: @user2124571 and that's fine now.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I update the query to show that "t2.c = '339' and t2.c ='0'" should read "t2.c1 = '339' and t2.c2 ='0'"

Comment: Now your query looks fine. Any issues?

Comment: None that I see! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Since `t2.c = '339' and t2.c ='0'` will not be true, I guess you looking for `IN` or `OR` *not* `AND` ;

```
Update t1 
Set t1.c ='6'
From t1
Inner Join t2 on t1.c = t2.c 
Where t2.c in ('339','0')
```

Or (after your correction)

```
Update t1 
Set t1.c ='6'
From t1
Inner Join t2 on t1.c = t2.c 
Where t2.c1 ='339' and t2.c2 ='0'
```

Comment: `+1` for catching that. I need some sleep. zzz `:D`